# Making CUI progress bar object in scala using CanBuildFrom

Tags: scala

now I am making CUI progress bar object in scala 2.11.7, which I am imitating the one found in F#, Console.showProgress, and which I found very nice. The progress bar I am trying to make can be used like:

```
pregressBar ((1 to 100)) { i =>
  doSomeWork(i)
}
```

and looks like:

```
67% [================================>                 ]
```

I expect this progressBar object to do some work based on the 1st argument sequence and returns the sequence containing the results of that work (which is really like map function).
And as I expect it to be like map function, the container class outputted by it needs to be same as the container class of its input. So when the input is List, the output is also List, when Array, the output is Array..
But as for now, my implementation only takes in List class, even though I am trying using CanBuildFrom.
Here is the code:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder
import scala.language.higherKinds

object progressBar {

  def apply[A, B, S[A] <: Seq[A]](seq: S[A])(f: A => B)
   (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[S[A], B, S[B]]): S[B] = {
    val result =
      for {i <- 0 until seq.size
         r = ((i.toDouble) / (seq.size.toDouble) * 100).toInt + 1
         _ = printf("%3d%% [%-50s]\r",r,"="*(r/2-1)+">")
         _ = System.out.flush
         v = f(seq(i))
      } yield v
    println
    result.to[S]
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // test
    progressBar(List(1,2,3)) {_ =>
     Thread sleep 100
     0
    }
  }
}
```

For example when I change the List(1,2,3) to Array in main part, just type mismatch error is thrown.　How can I fix this to work as expected?
I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Array` isn't a `Seq`, type inference has extra work to do.

One solution is an overload just for `Array`:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder
import scala.language.higherKinds

import collection.mutable.WrappedArray
import reflect.ClassTag

object progressBar {

  def apply[A, B, S[A] <: Seq[A]](seq: S[A])(f: A => B)
   (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[S[A], B, S[B]]): S[B] = {
    val result = seq.zipWithIndex map { case (v, i) =>
      val r = ((i.toDouble) / (seq.size.toDouble) * 100).toInt + 1
      printf("%3d%% [%-50s]\r",r,"="*(r/2-1)+">")
      System.out.flush
      f(v)
    }
    println
    result.to[S]
  }
  def apply[A, B : ClassTag](xs: Array[A])(f: A => B): Array[B] = {
    val w = apply(WrappedArray.make[A](xs))(f)
    w.array
  }
}

object Test extends App {

  // test
  progressBar(List(1,2,3)) { _ =>
    Thread sleep 1000
    0
  }
  progressBar.apply(Array(1,2,3)) { _ =>
    Thread sleep 1000
    0
  }
}
```

Also,

```
object X {
  implicit class Bar[A, C[A] <: Seq[A]](private val vs: C[A]) {
    def progress[B](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[C[A], B, C[B]]): C[B] =
      progressBar(vs)(f)(bf)
  }
  implicit class ArrayBar[A](private val vs: Array[A]) {
    def progress[B: ClassTag](f: A => B): Array[B] =
      (WrappedArray.make[A](vs) progress f).array
  }
}
```

allows

```
  import X._
  List(1,2,3) progress { x => Thread sleep 1000 ; x }
  Array(1,2,3) progress { x => Thread sleep 1000 ; x }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! That exactly solved my problem. and also thank you for refatctoring the ugly part I used for comprehension and _ assignments.. :)